# Disable Diagonal Movement in Unity 2D (but fluctuates between the two)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay. So I understand how to disable diagonal movement, but what I want to do is switch between them for every step. So If I hold Left and Up, the character with go left one, then up, then left again. Kind of like a staircase movement. Here's what I've got so far:

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (!isMoving)
    {
        input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (input.y != 0) input.x = 0;

        if (input != Vector2.zero)
        {
            var targetPos = transform.position;
            targetPos.x += input.x;
            targetPos.y += input.y;

            StartCoroutine(Move(targetPos));
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator Move(Vector3 targetPos)
{
    isMoving = true;

    while ((targetPos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude > Mathf.Epsilon)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.position = targetPos;

    isMoving = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing this code snippet will solve the problem completely.

```cs
public bool phase;
private void Update()
{
    if (!isMoving)
    {
        input.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        input.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        if (input != Vector2.zero)
        {
            var targetPos = transform.position;

            if (phase) targetPos.x += input.x;
            else targetPos.y += input.y;

            StartCoroutine(Move(targetPos));

            phase = !phase;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]